# How to bind a List to a Listview userControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, data-binding

I am trying to make a ListView of products I have in my Database with a specified userControl UI.

and this is my list.

```
 <ListView x:Name="ProductTable" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding GetProducts}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <v:ProductLineStyle/>

         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>

     <ItemsControl></ItemsControl>


 </ListView>
```

I try to bind it to a list I have in my code behind by either use the ItemSource property un XAML code or in code behind.

```
ProductTable.Items.Clear();
ProductTable.ItemsSource = GetProducts();
```

but I keep getting empty list items in the end.

[the number of items displayed in ListView is right but they should not be empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNmOV.png)

I checked my list I want to bind it with multiple times and it was not empty.

At first I tried changing from ListView to ListBox but it didn't work, and I tried to use the code behind of the userControl as the class of products but it appeared that the constructor of the userControl should not have parameter so I used another class because it would be easier.

That is the code in my userControl now

```
public ProductLineStyle()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public string ProductID { get; set; }
public string ProductName { get; set; }
public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
public int ProductQTé { get; set; }
```

and this is the XAML script

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Fill="#2A3E50">

</Rectangle>
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ID" Text="{Binding ProductID}" FontFamily="Inter Semi Bold" Margin="10" FontSize="20" Foreground="#01161E" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Product" Text="{Binding ProductName}" FontFamily="Inter Semi Bold" Margin="10" MaxWidth="400" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Qte" Text="{Binding ProductQTé}" FontFamily="Inter Semi Bold" Width="50" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Price" Text="{Binding ProductPrice}" FontFamily="Inter Semi Bold" Margin="10,10,30,10" MaxWidth="400" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

</DockPanel>
```

and this is the class I am using.

```
internal class Product
{
    public Product(string ID, string Name, int Price, int Qty) 
    {
        ProductID = ID;
        ProductName = Name;
        ProductPrice = Price;
        ProductQTé = Qty;
    }

    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int ProductQTé { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading and understanding the following articles will also enable you to understand your errors:

[Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-8.0)
[Dependency properties overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-8.0)

You must connect the `ProductLineStyle` control inside the `DataTemplate` with the item of the `ItemsControl`. You must bind the `ProductLineStyle` to the `Product` item.

- But to be able to do that all properties defined in the `ProductLineStyle` control must be defined as dependency properties. You are not allowed to assign a binding to a non dependency property.
- Next, because the `Product` class is a binding source, it must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If it doesn't you will create memory leaks.
- Don't operate on the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. Instead operate on the source collection. Aside from that, the `ItesControl.Items.Clear` call is redundant and only add costs to the performance. It forces the complete iteration of the collection in order to remove item by item. This operation uses the item index. This means, the bigger the collection the longer it will take to clear the collection. If you plan to replace the collection, then you don't have to clear it beforehand.
- In WPF you can't bind to methods. Your following code does not work:

  ```
  <ListView x:Name="ProductTable" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding GetProducts}" />
  ```

  You can only bind to public properties:

  ```
  <ListView x:Name="ProductTable" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" />
  ```

  Even if the binding had worked, you would later remove/override it by the explicit code-behind value assignment:

  ```
  // Never do this.
  // The following line overrides the Binding declared in XAML:
  ProductTable.ItemsSource = GetProducts();

  // Instead operate on the source collection of the data binding:
  this.Products = GetProducts();

  // Because replacing the collection instance is expensive, 
  // you should reuse it and replace the items.
  // Just make sure that Products is an ObservableCollection<T>
  // or any other collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged
  this.Products.Clear();
  IEnumerable<Product> newProducts = GetProducts();
  foreach (Product newProduct in newProducts)
  {
    this.Products.Add(newProduct);
  }
  ```

  Use one or the other (explicit property assignment or data binding). Prefer data binding.
- And another important detail: never set the `DataContext` of a control internally. Especially when this control is expected to have Binding defined on one or more of its properties.
  This will break all external data bindings:

  ```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
      <Product Id="Abc" />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <!-- Binding is unexpectedly broken and won't resolve, 
         because the ProductStyle internally changes 
         the value of DataContext: 'DataContext = this;' 
    -->
    <ProductStyle ProductId="{Binding Id}" />
  </Grid>
  ```

  The external `Binding` usually targets the current `DataContext`. Nobody expects that this value is manipulated saliently by the control.
  The point is that the correct `DataContext` value will be automatically inherited from the parent by the dependency property engine.
  In your scenario, this parent is the `ListBoxItem` and the inherited value is the *Product* item. Now you can easily bind the `ProductStyle` control to the current `DataContext`, the `Product`. The bindings will behave as expected

To fix your code, you must change your class design and implementations.

**Product.cs**

```cs
// This type must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
// If this type had been a child of DependencyObject
// it would have to implement properties as dependency properties instead.
internal class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Use the common and recommend C# naming conventions
  // which states that fields and parameter names
  // must use camelCase. PascalCase is only for types and properties and events.
  public Product(string id) 
  {
    this.ProductId = id;
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedArgs(propertyName));

  public string Id { get; set; }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
   
    // Only operate on the source collection Products.
    // Do not reference the ItemsControl.ItemsSource property directly
    // except for assigning a Binding.
    this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
    {
      new Product("A112"),
      new Product("B543")
    };
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Products}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <ProductLineStyle ProductId="{Binding Id}" />
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**ProductStyle.xaml.cs**

```cs
class ProductLineStyle : UserControl
{
  public string ProductId
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(ProductIdProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProductIdProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ProductId",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public ProductLineStyle()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    
     // Don't do this. This will break your external data bindings 
     // (the data bindings defined on the ProductStyle element)!
     // The correct DataContext value will be automatically inherited from the parent.
     // In this scenario, the parent is the ListBoxItem and the value the Product type.

    //this.DataContext = this;
  }
}
```

**ProductStyle.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ProductId}" />
</UserControl>
```

Follow the pattern for all properties of `Product` and the `ProductStyle` control.